# Google Map API V3 : Map is not displayed if I don't choose "The website .... would like to use your current location" on IE popup

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I use Google Map Api v3 and I've a problem with IE (11) location.

When i launch IE 11 the browser ask me (in a popup) if I want to be localized. It the same thing on others browsers (Edge, Firefox, Google Chrome, ...) but on other's browsers I can say "no" and the map is still showed (no localized).

On IE (11) I can't choose "no". I must **close the popup** if I don't want to be localized but In this case **the map is not showed** !!!
I would still like to display the map if I close the popup.

Have you got a solution please ?

Comment: Provide your code.

Comment: John M : Thank you but in preparing the code to show you I found the solution. I solved the problem by placing the instantiation of the Google Map before the geolocation test.

Answer (score 0):

My code (It may be able to help someone) :

```
// Var GoogleMap
var googleMap = {};
googleMap.map = {};

// Init Dom map
var domMAP = document.getElementById(config.CSS.IDs.map.google);

// Google map instance
googleMap.map = new google.maps.Map(domMAP, {
    center: config.settings.map.defaultPosition,
    zoom: config.settings.map.defaultZoom,
    mapTypeId: config.settings.map.typeId,
    fullscreenControl: config.settings.map.fullscreenControl
});

// Geolocation
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        googleMap.map.setCenter(pos);
        _initMap();
    }, function () {
        _setPositionWithSearch(config.settings.map.defaultName, function () {
            _initMap();
        });
    });
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    _setPositionWithSearch(config.settings.map.initialDefaultName, function () {
        _initMap();
    });
}
```